# Squid url_rewrite_program

Tags: proxy, squid

I would like to use the squid url_rewrite_program to get rid of adf.ly ads. I've already written a perl script on which I've taken the code from an example and this works fine. However I can't get it working in squid it just seems as it isn't doing anything?

I've tested the perl script via the command line and output looks exactly as I want it.
Can somebody help?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

# Turn off buffering to STDOUT
$| = 1;

# Read from STDIN
while (<>) {

my @elems = split; # splits $_ on whitespace by default

# The URL is the first whitespace-separated element.
my $url = $elems[0];

# Handle foo.example.com links and translate them to example.com
# with the rest of the URL intact (if present). Ignore warnings...
if ($url =~ m#^http://adf\.ly(/.*)?#i) {

    $url = substr $url, 22;

    print "$url\n";

}


else {

    # Unmodified URL
    print "$url\n";

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an overly complicated solution for the stated purpose.
You can get a more effective result by denying access based on a dstdomain acl

e.g.
acl deny_ads dstdomain .adf.ly
http_access deny deny_ads

This will prevent this squid's clients from accessing any urls in any subdomain of adf.ly. It's synchronous, requires no DNS lookups so it's also very fast.