# Squid url_rewrite_program. stdin always empty. Unable to parse squid msg with wgets

Tags: c, stdin, squid

I'm trying to redirect request from Squid to my app (written in C) by squid.conf:

```
http_port 3128
# some default configuration out of the box
url_rewrite_program /cygdrive/c/app.exe /cygdrive/c/app.conf
url_rewrite_children 1 startup=1 idle=1
```

The app runs correctly. But stdin never fills by Squid (by setting InternetProps -> Connections -> Lan settings Proxy connection settings localhost:3128). And wgets (stdio.h) command won't any read data.

According to the squid access.log the url was called:
1555677518.894  44096 ::1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 39 CONNECT www.google.com.ua:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.16.3 -

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char str[1000]
  while(1) {
    if (fgets(str, 100, stdin)!=NULL) {
      // do smth
    }
    // wait millis
  }
}
```

if to call app manually and write smth in stdin works fine.
I'm using Squid 3.5.28 built with Cygwin, also have tried 2.7 stable, but the same result.

Found an old post with a similar issue, but it wasn't resolved: [Squid url_rewrite_program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492825/squid-url-rewrite-program)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/937515/how-to-set-up-url-rewriting-under-squid-3-5-on-windows-10
The cause of empty output was how Cygwin models piping between Cygwin binary (squid) and native Windows binary.
Changed the OS to Unix (Debian) and recompiled app. Works fine :)